# Echoing results of a SELECT COUNT(*) query

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, echo

With my website I am showing different products in lots of different settings so to ensure that the number of results is correct I want to echo them with PHP. So far I have tried echoing them the way I know and that hasn't worked.

The code on the page I want to echo on is contains a require to my function files at the top. I have tried:

```
<?php
//Call the count_stock() function
$result_count = count_stock();
?>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php echo $result_count['COUNT(*)']; ?> results.</p>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php echo $result_count[0]; ?> results.</p>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php print_r($result_count[0]); ?> results.</p>
```

My function to execute the query is:

```
//create a function to count get_stock
function count_stock() {
    global $conn;
    //query the database to count the data entries in the stock table
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock';
    //use a prepared statement to enhance security
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result_count = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result_count;
}
```

Comment: what var_dump($result_count) return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function as :

```
function count_stock() {
        global $conn;
        //query the database to count the data entries in the stock table
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as tot FROM stock';
        //use a prepared statement to enhance security
        $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $result_count = $statement->fetch();
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $result_count['tot'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
//create a function to count get_stock
function count_stock() {
    global $conn;
    //query the database to count the data entries in the stock table
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock';
    //use a prepared statement to enhance security
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result_count = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result_count;
}
```

to

```
//create a function to count get_stock
function count_stock() {
    global $conn;
    //query the database to count the data entries in the stock table
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total_result FROM stock';
    //use a prepared statement to enhance security
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $row['total_result'];
}
```

And also change from

```
<?php
//Call the count_stock() function
$result_count = count_stock();
?>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php echo $result_count['COUNT(*)']; ?> results.</p>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php echo $result_count[0]; ?> results.</p>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php print_r($result_count[0]); ?> results.</p>
```

to

```
<?php
//Call the count_stock() function
$result_count = count_stock();
?>
<p>Showing 1-9 of <?php echo $result_count; ?> results.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `stock"; 
$result = $con->prepare($sql); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

The above code example uses a prepared statement, which is in many cases is probably unnecessary for the purpose of counting rows, so:

```
$nRows = $pdo->query('select count(*) from blah')->fetchColumn(); 
echo $nRows;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

**Note:** PDO has PDOStatement::rowCount(), which apparently does not work in MySql. What a pain